# Does the Greater Restoration spell grant knowledge about the effect it ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, healing

I have a really great hunch that my players will cast *greater restoration* on a person charmed by Levistus. Is there any consensus or RAW that states that the caster will learn anything about what is cured?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *Greater restoration* does not give special knowledge of the effect it cures.

[Spells only do what they say they do.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret)

The caster must choose which of the five effects of [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) to use (PHB, pg. 246):

> You imbue a creature you touch with positive energy to undo a debilitating effect. You can reduce the target's exhaustion level by one, or end one of the following effects on the target:
>
> - One effect that charmed or petrified the target
> - One curse, including the target's attunement to a cursed magic item
> - Any reduction to one of the target's ability scores
> - One effect reducing the target's hit point maximum

They can choose to end a charmed effect, but they learn nothing about how the charm effect came about, since the spell doesn't say anything about learning anything about the source of the cured effect.